# How to extract the last digits of strings using regular expressions?

Tags: r, regex, replace, names

I have a bunch of colnames

```
L_1_3
L_2_23
L_3_91
L_3_16
```

I want to replace these colnames with new names using the last digits following the _ like this:

```
3
23
91
16
```

I've tried `colnames(X) <- gsub("L_\\d\\d_", "", colnames(X))` which works for strings with double digits at the end. I want one that works for both single and double digits.

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an option with positive lookahead:

```
gsub(".+_(?=\\d+$)", "", X, perl = TRUE)
[1] "3"  "23" "91" "16"
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(X, "\\d+$")
#[1] "3"  "23" "91" "16"
```

#### data

```
X <- c("L_1_3", "L_2_23", "L_3_91", "L_3_16")
```

Answer (score 5):

If that is the pattern that works for you for 2 digits, the only thing you would have to do is to make one of the digits optional using `?`

```
L_\\d\\d?_
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PMM8x4/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/zpcgEE)

---

If you must match the whole pattern, you could use a capturing group and use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string and use the group in the replacement.

```
^L_\\d\\d?_(\\d+)$
```

*In parts*

```
^      Start of string
L_     Match L_
\d     Match a digit
\d?    Match a digit and repeat 0 or 1 times
_      Match _
(      Capture group 1
  \d+  Match a digit and repeat 1 or more times
)      Close group
$      End of string
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4Y1n8Q/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/AyHRRN)

```
X <- c("L_1_3", "L_2_23", "L_3_91", "L_3_16")
gsub("^L_\\d\\d?_(\\d+)$", "\\1", X)
```

Output

```
[1] "3"  "23" "91" "16"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a regular expression that does it.
It gets anything until a non-digit followed by the capture group of one or more digits at the end. And replaces by the the capture group.

```
sub('.*[^[:digit:]]{1}([[:digit:]]+$)', '\\1', x)
#[1] "3"  "23" "91" "16"
```

A regex that works for single and double digits but neither more nor less would be

```
sub('.*[^[:digit:]]{1}([[:digit:]]{1,2}$)', '\\1', x)
#[1] "3"  "23" "91" "16"
```

**Data**

```
x <- scan(what = character(), text = '
L_1_3
L_2_23
L_3_91
L_3_16')
```

Comment: I think `"^.*?(\\d+)$"` works just as well, doesn't it?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes it does, post as an answer and I'll upvote. It's much better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Tried to keep it as simple as possible

```
sub(".*_(\\d+$)", "\\1", X)
[1] "3"  "23" "91" "16"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the simplest regex:

```
sub(".*\\_", "", tmp)
```